# Create multi level menu from 2 tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create 2 tables like below:
Category(id, category_name)
Product(id, product_name, category_id)
How do I create a menu like that with SQL Server?
A category
++ Product 1
++ Product 2 ...
B category
++ Product 3
++ Product 4
Thanks for watching!

Comment: what do you mean with "create a menu"?

Comment: help me use sql to create a structure like that, display with html and asp no problem with me

Comment: As posted this makes no sense. As a random guess I would say you join the two tables together and order them in the order you want. Of course in the tables you posted there is nothing to use as an order. This might be a better place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: and where is the code you've tried?

Comment: Here is what I tried

Comment: use Demo
Go

select *
from Category as c
left join Product as p
on c.id = p.category_id
where (c.category_nm like '%Window%' OR p.product_nm like '%Gla%')

select * from category

Answer (score -1):

You can JOIN the 2 tables and list them according to "category_name". I would do the following:

`SELECT * FROM Category INNER JOIN Product ON Category.id = Product.category_id ORDER BY Category.category_name, Product.product_name ASC`